# brief standard code to clean most common data frame invalid entries

Tags: r, data-cleaning

What is the specific, brief R-code you would  use frequently, to impute / remove / clean  the *80% most common* invalid entries 
in a data frame?
(I always receive data frames with: NAs, blanks, characters in numeric columns).

simple specific data frame example
to clean common invalid entries:
 (my real ex. can have 10000+ rows and 25 variables...)

```
         var1  var2  var3  
gene001  10    100   1000  
gene002  20    NA    2000  
gene003  aa    NA    3000  
gene004  40    400    blank!  
gene005  50    500   5000  
gene006  60    600   6000
```

I never know in advance what the "culprit" values will be,
(or in which DF column they will appear)...

I'd like the missing values to show imputed / substituted valid values
 with a column average/median values.

Similar for invalid "string" values in numeric-only columns.

**Objective:** to quickly clean new DFs I receive with the same common problems, in a standard way,
before using randomForest.

Comment: Here's good course on coursera https://www.coursera.org/course/getdata

Comment: Also here's one good book on this subject https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/de_Jonge+van_der_Loo-Introduction_to_data_cleaning_with_R.pdf

Comment: No, sadly, all single, unified R packages to detect, validate and clean data only cover 50% of the most common data value problems. This is a consequence of the data scientist collective bargaining agreement with R Core in order to ensure job security.

Comment: @ grubjesic thanks for the referrals to pdf and course. Both excellent.   But what I'm looking for is a general data format cleaning solution.   (ie: an R pkg or maybe a user-written R function to deal with the most common problems in CSV files or in R-data frames (ie: NAs, empty strings, etc).

Comment: @joran: Well, even a pkg or user-written function to deal (quickly & simply), with 50% of the data cleaning solutions, would be very nice! Any references to such humble beginnings?  :-) (R pkg or user-written functions?)

Comment: You could play around with `awk` probably. I don't think R can do *anything* without importing the data.

Comment: Thank you, David. I've used AWK extensively before. I'll use AWK in the CSV side, before I read data into a data frame. But, I'm still still hoping to find a single and simple R package/user-written function to clean common data format problems in a data frame, AFTER the data has been read/imported.

Comment: It would make a good (edited) question if rather than asking "is there a package that does this", you enumerated as many issues as you'd like to see dealt with, answered those you could, and posed a question about doing it better/more competely ...

Comment: Good start.  Can you be a little bit more precise about enumerating problems and what you'd like to do about them?  Can you give a set of test data with the desired results?  Can you show how you'd get started? (PS: don't include comments in questions ...)

Comment: ... and what do you want the results to look like?

Comment: Thank you for your patient guidance, Ben!  Since I don't know in advance what the "culprit" values will be (or in which DF column they will appear),  I'd  like the missing values to show imputed / substituted valid values with a column average/median. Similar for "string" values in numeric columns. Objective: to quickly deal with new DFs I receive, in a quick, standard way, before using randomForest.

Comment: are you sure you get blank values in numeric columns? when I use `read.csv()` with default options, these get automatically converted to `NA` ...

Comment: Yes, you are right Ben! anyhow - I am happy to be able to substitute the  NAs and char strings in numeric-only cols by Column averages, since these are the 2 most common data frame problems I get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate data:

```
dd <- read.csv(text="
var1,var2,var3  
10,100,1000  
20,NA,2000  
aa,NA,3000  
40,400,
50,500,5000  
60,600,6000 ")
```

Column-wise clean-up function (you can add more logic to this if there are other cases you want to handle):

```
cleanup <- function(x) {
    ## ASSUME all columns should be numeric
    if (is.factor(x) || is.character(x)) {
        x <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(as.character(x)))
    }
    ## impute median
    m <- median(x,na.rm=TRUE)
    x[is.na(x)] <- m
    return(x)
}
```

Apply cleanup to all columns:

```
dd[] <- lapply(dd,cleanup)
```

Comment: Thank you Ben! Very clear solution....(also learned a lot about how to formulate my questions in StackO: "this is what I have and this is what I need"...Have a super day and thank you again. You are a great teacher!